# Pine: I have to convert this into pine v4 or v5 to publish on tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I have to convert this into pine v4 or v5 to publish on tradingview. Please suggest  what to modify/add.

```
enter code here


study(title="3 Moving Averages", shorttitle="50,100,200 MAs", overlay=true)
exponential = input(true, title="50,100,200 Exponential MA")

src = close

ma50 = exponential ? ema(src, 50) : sma(src, 50)
ma100 = exponential ? ema(src, 100) : sma(src, 100)
ma200 = exponential ? ema(src, 200) : sma(src, 200)
plot( ma50, color=fuchsia, style=line, title="MMA50", linewidth=1)
plot( ma100, color=green, style=line, title="MMA100", linewidth=1)
plot( ma200, color=orange, style=line, title="MMA200", linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator('Moving Averages', '50,100,200 MAs', true)
exponential = input(true, '50,100,200 Exponential MA')

src = input.source(close, "Source")

ma50 = exponential ? ta.ema(src, 50) : ta.sma(src, 50)
ma100 = exponential ? ta.ema(src, 100) : ta.sma(src, 100)
ma200 = exponential ? ta.ema(src, 200) : ta.sma(src, 200)
plot(ma50, color=color.new(color.fuchsia, 0), title='MMA50', linewidth=1)
plot(ma100, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='MMA100', linewidth=1)
plot(ma200, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), title='MMA200', linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pine editor, look for the 3 dots on the right (next to publish). You will see an option to auto convert.